# Isn't there a way to disable the Personal side of a Microsoft Account?

Tags: microsoft-office-365

I am very sure I saw something within the last year saying that you could disable the Personal side of a Microsoft Account. Of course, we know that a user, name@company.com has both a Work or School account and a Personal account associated with that same email address, confusingly. I definitely recall reading the personal side could be disabled in order to avoid that confusion for employees. Now I can't find this anywhere. It was something done by the user themselves, not like a group policy setting or any admin level thing, as I recall.

Can someone point me to this process? Thanks.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12412/microsoft-account-how-to-close-account

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you may consider adding aliases as email address to your microsoft account and remove your Personal account. Here are the detailed steps:

1.log into your manage [your account aliases page](https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=12&ct=1461835256&rver=6.5.6510.0&wp=sa_20min&wreply=https:%2F%2Faccount.live.com%2Fnames%2Fmanage%3Fnoteid%3Dnote_makeprimarysuccess%26notelevel%3D1%26alias%3D%252fsowvcfngtk0mh%252f9uumb7on1ri6nyzczoq0%252fc6lqydulvc%252fondbtwkhoxztzjxq2z8pirjwxppapjr6b0z1bqgo7iphp8cvrzj5x%252bwjx%252frnatpezpxhfbvinmst07zeirquo%252b2wqbicg693vv49sfw%253d%253d%253a1%253a3&lc=1033&id=38936&mkt=en-us&uaid=d2d358d4617e44398ceb973bee9610e6) with your personal account, and then click “add email alias”.

2.Complete the crete a new email address and add it as an alias.

3.On the next page, make *** Email address is removed for privacy *** the primary account and then remove your Personal account.